# TUG website down?

Tags: tug

Has anybody had problems going to https://tug.org/texlive/ ?  I've tried over the weekend and today is still unreachable.  Tried different browsers on different devices with only time outs. Ping says address is unreachable.

Comment: Works fine here, and also on https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/tug.org

Comment: Must be my ISP and an issue in their routing table.  I see that TexLive is available on CTAN.  Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: Argh!  CTAN links to TUG.  I guess I'll just have to wait it out until the entry times out.

Comment: See this comment from Barbara (whi is having computer issues and can't post here) https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54732269#54732269